# How to index all the terms in the document in Lucene?

Tags: java, lucene, indexing, full-text-search

The documents that I am indexing are very large. Lucene by default only indexes the first 10,000 terms of a document to avoid OutOfMemory errors. So I am getting incorrect hits while searching the Index. How could I index all the terms in the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength`. Specifies maximum field length (in number of tokens/terms) in IndexWriter constructors

You can set maximum value as part of IndexWriter constructor [MAX_VALUE - Lucene Recent Versions](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_4_0/api/all/index.html?org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.html)  or [UNLIMITED - Lucene Older Versions](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_2/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.html#UNLIMITED).

You could also use `IndexWriter.setMaxFieldLength(int)` to override the value set by the constructor.